# Postgres having query with any in array

Tags: postgresql

Using the following query:

```sql
select bc.name, b.* from blog b
left join blog_to_blog_category btbc on b.id = btbc.blog_id
join blog_category bc on btbc.blog_category_id = bc.id
group by b.id, bc.name
having array_agg(btbc.blog_category_id) @> array[5,6];
```

It will show me blogs that are in both category 5 AND 6.  How do I alter this so it will show me blogs that are in either category 5 OR 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [*overlaps* operator `&&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) instead of the *contains* operator `@>` for the two arrays.

You can however simplify by not using an aggregation but just a `WHERE` condition (with a normal `JOIN` instead of the `LEFT JOIN`):

```
select bc.name, b.*
from blog b
join blog_to_blog_category btbc on b.id = btbc.blog_id
join blog_category bc on btbc.blog_category_id = bc.id
where bc.id in (5, 6)
group by b.id, bc.name
```

<sub>(I suspect this will also be more efficient / optimised better than the array aggregate)</sub>

Comment: Thank you.  What is reason that left join shouldn't be used?

Comment: Without the `having` clause, you'd get all blogs (and `null` for the category name) when doing a left join and filtering only categories